# React Update Profile for user through a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, use-effect

I'm trying to build a Update profile form where a user can change his details and onSubmit the new data will be sent to `PUT/users` end point to update the details in the database. The form will have the old values pre filled (gotten through a `GET` request to the same `/users` endpoint). To access this endpoint we also need to send a basic auth header with email and password. Now I'm making two fetch requests one to get the existing details and one to PUT the new details. My first `GET` request is successfully made and I can see the data prefilled but my second `POST` request doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
Here is how my code looks. https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-breeze-itinq?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
const getUsers = async () => {
   let myHeaders = new Headers();
   myHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + credentials);
   const requestOptions = {
   method: 'GET',
   headers: myHeaders,
   redirect: 'follow',
   };

   try {
     const response = await fetch(`${APIlink}/users`, requestOptions);
     const result = await response.json();
     setData(result);
   } catch (err) {
     setErr('Incorrect Password. Please Retry.');
   }
 };

useEffect(() => {
 getUsers();
}, []);
```

You useEffect gets called on Every render as you have not mentioned any dependency array. So what happens in your case is,

your component renders --> useEffect gets called --> make api call --> you set state --> component re-renders --> useEffect gets called --> make api call and this cycle continues forever .

```
useEffect(() => {
  ....
}); => this useEffect will trigger on first render and every re-render

useEffect(() => {
  ...
}, []); => this will trigger only for the first time when the component is mounted


useEffect(() => {
  ...
}, [value]);  => triggers on first render and whenever the value changes
```

Comment: Thank you! The second `PUT` request in the `handleSubmit` function still doesn't work, can you tell me where I'm going wrong with that?

Comment: can you add a console log inside your handleSubmit and check whether it is getting printed ?

Comment: it is not getting printed, I have applied the same logic for the sign up form and it works there

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with [lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) in class based components, you usually do API calls in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. This method is called only once after the first render. More on this: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

In your code, you are using `useEffect` which is more or less like the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method, which is called on every render. this is why,

> The page loads and I can see an endless string of GET requests in the network tab.

More on this: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

The solution would be to make your `useEffect` hook behave like a `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, which is essentially telling the `useEffect` hook to run only once.

If we examine a hook, it is made up of two components:

1. Callback function (required)
2. Dependency list of props (optional)

which looks like this:

```js
useEffect(Callback, [Dependencies]);
```

An example would be:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(props.color)
}, [props.color]);
```

So essentially we are saying that whenever the prop `color` is changed, we want to log the value of `color`.

Seeing as how this is, if we pass an empty array of dependencies, the `useEffect` hook will only run once and that is what you should do. Do note that if a dependencies array is not passed, it will still behave like `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method i.e it will be executed on every render.

**Solution if you just skipped to this part is**:

Pass an empty dependencies list in your `useEffect` hook.

More on hooks:

1. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#explanation-why-effects-run-on-each-update
2. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: Thank you! The second PUT request in the handleSubmit function still doesn't work, can you tell me where I'm going wrong with that?

Comment: I don't see an issue with the handleSubmit method but the validation part might be giving you trouble. Try to remove the isValid check and then submit the form.

Comment: I've used the same validation for my sign up page and it works, here even after removing validation the POST request is not made